# Wine programs can't open files from another hard drive

Tags: wine

I can't open any files (music, video, any type of files) on my second hard drive via Wine. If I copy that file to home folder, then I can. But I don't want to copy each file (I haven't got much space on first one) 
**How can I make it work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Create a link to the second hard drive

1. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Run `ln -s /path/to/second/hard/drive ~/second-hard-drive` (replace `/path/to/second/hard/drive` with the actual path to the second hard drive)

This will create a link called `second-hard-drive` to your second hard drive inside your home directory. You can use that as if it's a regular directory containing everything in your second hard drive.

Comment: It didn't work. I don't know why. ((

Comment: Did the link appear and does it contain the contents of the second hard drive?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything new in home directory. But if I type that code again, it says that link exists